# Uncaught ReferenceError: doIt is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

So i have the following problem. I have a title and a description written on the same row. I want to move the description in the next div using javascript. I have multiple items and i am trying to have the same effect for each one of them without writing 6 functions, one for each What am i doing wrong?

```
function doIt(text) {


        for (var i = 1; i <= 6: i++) {

            if (('panel' + i.toString()) == text) {
                if (document.getElementById('move' + i.toString()).parentElement.getAttribute('id') ==
                    'panel'+i.toString()) {
                    document.getElementById('div'+i.toString()).appendChild(
                        document.getElementById('move' + i.toString())



                    );
                    document.getElementById('div'+i.toString()).insertBefore(
                        document.getElementById('move' + i.toString()), document.getElementById('div'+i.toString()).firstChild);
                    document.getElementById('move' + i.toString()).innerHTML = document.getElementById('move' + i).innerHTML.substr(1);
                } else {

                    document.getElementById('panel' + i.toString()).appendChild(
                        document.getElementById('move' + i.toString()));
                    document.getElementById('move' + i.toString()).innerHTML = '-' + document.getElementById('move' + i.toString()).innerHTML;



                }
            }


        }
    }
```

This is part of the html code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <center>
                <a href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" style="text-decoration:none; color: black ;">
                    <div id="panel1" class="panel-heading" onclick="doIt(this.id)">

                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="display:inline-block;">

                            President 3
                        </h4>

                        <h6 id="move1" href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" style="display: inline-block;">-Scurta descriere president 3</h6>

                    </div>

                </a>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <center id="div1">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please make sure that the JS file is loaded in when clicking the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 error : 
1- syntax error in loop for `(var i = 1; i <= 6: i++)` => `for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)` 
2- js file not loaded

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nqym3s4b/3/

Comment: Thank you a lot. I changed the : to ; and it instantly worked. Thank you for your keen eyes @Mgasmi

Comment: you're welcom :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in javascript code(for loop). First correct and then see the next issue.

```
let panels = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-heading');

for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
  panels[i].addEventListener('click', doIt, false);
}
```

Also, do not use onclick event. Try adding event listeners.
jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tvf7p4zc/)